# Physical meaning of harmonic function?

Tags: curvature, differentiation

In complex numbers, we define a [harmonic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function) as a twice continuously differentiable function such that the [Laplace operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) acting on it gives zero. Can anybody explain me the physical interpretation of harmonic functions?

Comment: does it mean its a continuously increasing or continuously decreasing function?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20714/2451

Comment: harmonic has to do with harmony ,this is an interesting answer http://math.stackexchange.com/q/123620/

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I'd like to recommend Tristan Needham's book *Visual Complex Analysis* which is an excellent text and very accessible to physicists. In his own words (p. 515):

> The Laplacian of $\Phi$ at $p$ measures the amount by which the
> average value of $\Phi$ on an infinitesimal circle centered at $p$
> exceeds the value of $\Phi$ at $p$ itself. More precisely, if $r$ is
> the infinitesimal radius of this circle, then
>
> $$\langle \Phi \rangle - \Phi(p) = \frac{1}{4}r^2 \Delta \Phi$$

Towards a derivation, consider the scalar field $\Phi$, and a gradient vector field $\nabla \Phi$. Physically, one may think of $\Phi$ as a potential, and $\nabla\Phi$ as the lines of force. The flux out of a circle $C$ of radius $r$ is,

$$2\pi r \partial_r \langle \Phi \rangle$$

If $\Phi$ is harmonic, then $V$ is sourceless, and the flux vanishes as a consequence of the definition above of the Laplacian. From this, we see $\langle \Phi \rangle$ is independent of $r$, and it follows that if we shrink $C$ down to the center point $p$, this $r$-independent value must be $\Phi(p)$.

Now suppose the flux is non-zero, but that the flux-density $\Delta \Phi$ is constant. As a consequence of Gauss' divergence theorem, the flux must be of the form, $nr^2 \Delta \Phi$. Inserting into our original flux, we find,

$$\partial_r \langle \Phi \rangle = \frac{1}{2}r\Delta \Phi$$

which you can integrate to find the first definition of the Laplacian. To complete the derivation, as Freedham states, it is 'only necessary to observe that the Laplacian of an arbitrary $\Phi$ is constant within an infinitesimal circle.' Freedham goes on to show how this result can be used to geometrically prove the conformal invariance of the Laplacian. This implies a harmonic function is only harmonic if and only if all conformal transformations maintain its harmonicity.

Comment: That book is a certainly a great joy to read. Needham is supposedly working on a "Visual Differential Geometry" - I'm keen to see that.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Really, a visual differential geometry? That would be awesome! (Although, there are already some great books for that, e.g. by Lee). I'd also like to see an algebraic geometry one.

Comment: Yes indeed. I tried to contact Needham to ask roughly when this would be out, but I didn't get an answer. I guess he gets asked that a great deal and is getting a bit tired of being asked.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance I'll send him an e-mail myself, maybe he's in a good mood :)

Comment: @Selene Routley , can you tell me what are the prerequisites to understand the physics in the book of Needham Tristan?

Comment: @Dey It's not a physics text, but a complex analysis one. Prerequisites are hard to state since i am 57 years old and don't really recall how i came to fully understand many of these subjects. But if you can understand a derivation of Cauchy's Integral Theorem and that of the Cauchy Riemann equations, then i would say you'd be there. I was ready for this field after first year uni mathematics - analysis (as opposed to algebraic stuff). If you can borrow it from a library, give it a try - it is a lovely, almost poetic text

Answer (score 2):

Imagine an elastic fabric streched over a flat frame. If the frame is then bent out of the plane, the shape of the fabric will follow. The equation
$
\nabla^2 u = 0
$ can be used to model such, where $u$ represents the displacement of the frabric with respect to the initial configuration.

As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50274/intuitive-interpretation-of-the-laplacian) the laplacian $\nabla^2 u(x_0)$ is proportial to the average of $u(x)-u(x_0)$ in a small ball around $x_0$. So having $\nabla^2 u = 0$ means that at every point, $u$ would equal to the average of its neighboring points.

With this interpretation, it can be seen why the fabric should satisfy such an equation. If you think about it in 1D as a chain of points that are joined by springs, the configuration with minimal energy is where each point is in between its neighbours.

[image: Elastic chain and laplace equation]