# Are Laplace Operator and mean curvature exactly the same thing for 2D function?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, differentiation

Let's assume we study 2D function/surface f(x,y).

Then Laplace Operator is defined as: $$\nabla^2 f=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}$$

And the mean curvature: let $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ be the principal curvatures, then the mean curvature is defined as: $$H=\frac12(\kappa_1+\kappa_2)$$

We can ignore the coefficient $\frac12$ for discussion. The question is: are these two exactly the same for 2D functions? If not what is the difference? I am not quite familiar with differential geometry...

Comment: What? *Curvature* is a property of a manifold, and the Laplace operator is an operator on smooth functions - how could these *possibly* be the same?

Comment: But can we write a curved surface as f(x,y) in 2D situation?

Comment: Like f=x^2-y^2 is a curved surface but with 0 mean curvature...

Comment: Like in 1D, the second order derivative is the curvature for a line...

Comment: Yes, you can write the height of a 2D membrane as f(x,y) given the curvature is not too large. Similarly, if the curvature is not too large, you can use the Monge gauge and approximate the curvature using the Laplacian.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20714/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic it's not a duplicate. I know these two are related and similar, but I am wondering whether they are exactly the same.. if not, what are the differences...

Comment: @alarge Thanks.. I am trying to learn what is a Monge gauge...

Comment: See for example http://www.cmu.edu/biolphys/deserno/pdf/membrane_theory.pdf, eq. (20) and the "Box 5" that follows it.

Comment: @alarge Thanks for your information! I understand now...