# Physical meaning of the vector Laplace operator

Tags: operators, differential-geometry, differentiation, curvature

I have seen [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20714/laplace-operators-interpretation) a question asking for the physical interpretation of the Laplace operator for a scalar field. However, there is also a vectorial version of this operator, the **vector laplace operator**, which is defined as follows:

$$
\nabla^{2} \mathbf{A}=\nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A})-\nabla \times(\nabla \times \mathbf{A})
$$

being both $\mathbf {A}$ and $\nabla^{2} \mathbf{A}$ vector fields. In particular, in Cartesian coordinates it would take this form: $$
\nabla^{2} \mathbf{A}=\left(\nabla^{2} A_{x}, \nabla^{2} A_{y}, \nabla^{2} A_{z}\right)
$$

Since the Laplacian $\nabla^2 f$ of a scalar field $f$ at a point $p$ measures by how much the average value of $f$ over small balls centered at $p$ deviates from $f(p)$, what would be the physical or intuitive meaning of the vector Laplacian?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning is exactly the same. The Laplacian of a vector field at a point $p$ measures the amount by which the average of the *vector* over small balls centered at $p$ differs from the vector at $p$. In fact, since scalars and vectors are tensors of rank $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ respectively, the Laplacian can be applied to tensors of any rank.

For the sake of completeness, the Laplacian in tensor notation (curved space without non-metricity) is:

$$\nabla^i \nabla_i = g^{ij} \nabla_i \nabla_j$$