# Relativistic Correction to the Hydrogen Atom and Spherically Symmetric Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, atomic-physics, perturbation-theory

We know, the lowest order relativistic correction to the Hamiltonian for the Hydrogen atom is
$$H^{'}=-\frac{p^{4}}{8m^{3}c^{2}}$$
Where,
$$p=-\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla$$
So, is $p^{2}=-\hbar^{2}\nabla^{2}$ and $p^{4}=\hbar^{4}\nabla^{2}(\nabla^{2})$?

In various sources, for calculating the first order correction to the energy, a fact has been utilized that the perturbation is spherically symmetric.

a) First of all, what should a spherically symmetric operator look like?

b) Secondly, does this mean that the operator $\nabla^{2}(\nabla^{2})$ is spherically symmetric? If so, how to prove that? Or is there any easy way to intuitively understand that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is a good exercise to do it for arbitrary perturbation potential, starting from the Dirac equation. The resulting form is actually used to model spin-orbit coupling in semiconductors, although replacing $mc^2$ by $E_g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An operator is called spherically symmetric when it is invariant under rotations. The [Laplace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) is invariant under rotations and translation (the Euclidean transformations).

> In fact, the algebra of all scalar linear differential operators, with
> constant coefficients, that commute with all Euclidean
> transformations, is the polynomial algebra generated by the Laplace
> operator. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator)

For a hint to how to show that indeed the Laplace operator is invariant under rotations see e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970892/show-laplace-operator-is-rotationally-invariant) math.SE post.
For some intuitive hints on why the Laplace operator is spherically symmetric see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50274/intuitive-interpretation-of-the-laplacian-operator) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20714/laplace-operators-interpretation) posts on math.SE and physics.SE.

Comment: Thank you for the resources. I will look into those.